# Speed difference of loop Inside vs Outside Function

Tags: r, microbenchmark

Out of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53971364/split-a-vector-and-summing-values/53971606#53971606) resulted a discussion when benchmarking the various solutions. Consider the following code

```
# global environment is empty - new session just started
# set up
set.seed(20181231)
n <- sample(10^3:10^4,10^3)
for_loop <- function(n) {
  out <- integer(length(n))
  for(k in 1:length(out)) {
    if((k %% 2) == 0){
      out[k] <- 0L
      next
    }
    out[k] <- 1L
    next
  }
  out
}
# benchmarking
res <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  for_loop = {
    out <- integer(length(n))
    for(k in 1:length(out)) {
      if((k %% 2) == 0){
        out[k] <- 0L
        next
      }
      out[k] <- 1L
      next
    }
    out
  },
  for_loop(n),
  times = 10^4
)
```

Here are the benchmarking results for the exact same loops, one packed in a function, the other not

```
# Unit: microseconds
#        expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    for_loop 3216.773 3615.360 4120.3772 3759.771 4261.377 34388.95 10000   b
# for_loop(n)  162.280  180.149  225.8061  190.724  211.875 26991.58 10000  a 
ggplot2::autoplot(res)
```

[image: benchmarking2]

As can be seen, there is a drastic difference in efficiency. What is the underlying reason for this?

To be clear, the question is not about the task solved by the above code (which could be done much more elegantly) but merely about efficiency discrepancy between a regular loop and a loop wrapped inside a function.

Comment: I understand. I did however empty my environment and restarted a new session before every trial, so the only variable extra in the global environment is `for_loop`. Do you believe it could still be the reason behind that lag?

Comment: I've deleted that comment; the real reason is in my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation is that functions are "just-in-time" compiled, whereas interpreted code is not.  See `?compiler::enableJIT` for a description.

If you want a demonstration of the difference, run

```
compiler::enableJIT(0)
```

before any of your code (*including* the creation of the `for_loop` function).  This disables JIT compiling for the rest of that session.  Then the timing will be much more similar for the two sets of code.

You have to do this before the creation of the `for_loop` function, because once it gets compiled by the JIT compiler, it will stay compiled, whether JIT is enabled or not.

Comment: That's interesting. But I am a little bit lost with the `with/without` function: you are saying "the 'with function' version took longer: there's more overhead being measured". But didn't the result indicate the reverse?

Comment: My explanation was a mess; sorry.  I've rewritten it to be a lot clearer.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I've tested with `compiler::enableJIT(0)` and just like you said the results were similar (~2.2 millis.). How should interpret the first `microbenchmark` results? Are those faster results "cheated" or "not real"?

Comment: As far as I know they're fine, it was my alternate timing code that was wrong, so I've deleted that.

Comment: What I meant was `compiler::enableJIT(3)` (default) and `compiler::enableJIT(0)` yield different benchmarking results (`~4k and~200 micro.` for the former and `~2.4k and ~2.2k micro.` for the latter - using `microbenchmark`). So my questions: Which benchmarks are more meaningful? Is the `~200 micro.` benchmark "real" or is it omitting computation time that would actually occur when running the code in a program?

Comment: It will only count the compilation time once.  If your program only calls the function a few times instead of 10000 times, compilation time will matter a lot more.