# Why does wrapping this loop in a function speed it up by 8x?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of loops vs. *apply functions in R. Here, I did an experiment where I compute the first 10,000 triangular numbers in 3 different ways.

1. `unwrapped`: a simple for loop
2. `wrapped`: I take the exact same loop from before, but wrap it in a function.
3. `vapply`: Using `vapply` and an anonymous function.

The results surprised me in two different ways.

1. Why is `wrapped` 8x faster than `unwrapped` (?!?!) My intuition is that given `wrapped` actually does more stuff (defines a function and then calls it), it should have been slower.
2. Why are they both so much faster than vapply? I would have expected vapply to be able to do some kind of optimization that performs at least as well as the loops.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  unwrapped = {
    x <- numeric(10000)
    for (i in 1:10000) {
      x[i] <- i * (i + 1) / 2
    }
    x
  },
  wrapped = {
    tri_nums <- function(n) {
      x <- numeric(n)
      for (i in 1:n) {
        x[i] <- i * (i + 1) / 2
      }
      x
    }
    tri_nums(10000)
    },
  vapply = vapply(1:10000, \(i) i * (i + 1) / 2, numeric(1)),
  check = 'equal'
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr      min       lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
#>  unwrapped 2652.487 3006.888 3445.896 3150.7555 3832.094  7029.949   100
#>    wrapped  398.534  414.010  455.333  439.7445  469.307   656.074   100
#>     vapply 4942.000 5154.639 5937.333 5453.2880 5969.760 13730.718   100
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: It's actually even better if you don't redefine the function on each pass.

Comment: Related (for the first comparison): [Speed difference of loop Inside vs Outside Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974449/speed-difference-of-loop-inside-vs-outside-function); [Why is running R code inside a function faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859458/why-is-running-r-code-inside-a-function-faster)

Comment: @Henrik, good find, this felt like it had to be a dupe but I didn't see those two. Thank you. For the record, I do add a bit more context than those two answers ... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's byte-compiling your function.

We can confirm just-in-time (JIT) compilation with:

```r
compiler::enableJIT(-1)
# [1] 3                        # <--- this is the previous JIT level
```

where negative returns the current level unchanged, and a value of 3 means highest JIT compiling level. I'm not certain what steps each level is doing, but we can make a simple test to compare them. (See [`?enableJIT`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/compiler/html/compile.html) for more info.)

```r
compiler::enableJIT(0)
# [1] 3
tri_nums <- function(n) {
  x <- numeric(n)
  for (i in 1:n) {
    x[i] <- i * (i + 1) / 2
  }
  x
}
bench::mark(
  unwrapped = {
    x <- numeric(10000)
    for (i in 1:10000) {
      x[i] <- i * (i + 1) / 2
    }
    x
  },
  JIT0 = tri_nums(10000),
  vapply = vapply(1:10000, \(i) i * (i + 1) / 2, numeric(1))
)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_al…¹ gc/se…² n_itr  n_gc total…³ result memory     time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list> <list>     <list>     <list>  
# 1 unwrapped    8.21ms    8.7ms      113.   78.2KB    7.07    48     3   424ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 JIT0         7.26ms   7.72ms      128.   78.2KB    9.84    52     4   407ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 3 vapply       5.97ms    6.5ms      152.   78.2KB    9.51    64     4   421ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​mem_alloc, ²​`gc/sec`, ³​total_time
```

(I can't put all three levels in at once, since I believe the JIT check is done when we call it as well as when we define it. I'm really not qualified to speak to this level of R-internal, so ... please correct me and/or add amplifying information.)

Doing this again for levels 1-3 and copy/pasting the relevant `bench::mark` rows, we see:

```r
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_al…¹ gc/se…² n_itr  n_gc total…³ result memory     time       gc      
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:by>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list> <list>     <list>     <list>  
# 1 unwrapped    8.21ms    8.7ms      113.   78.2KB    7.07    48     3   424ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 JIT0         7.26ms   7.72ms      128.   78.2KB    9.84    52     4   407ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 JIT1        419.6µs  502.5µs     1923.  108.7KB    0      962     0   500ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 JIT2        413.4µs  494.3µs     1971.  108.7KB    0      986     0   500ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 2 JIT3        426.7µs  498.3µs     1981.  108.7KB    0      991     0   500ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# 3 vapply       5.97ms    6.5ms      152.   78.2KB    9.51    64     4   421ms <dbl>  <Rprofmem> <bench_tm> <tibble>
# # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​mem_alloc, ²​`gc/sec`, ³​total_time
```

showing that the vast majority of gains are in the first level of byte-compiling (not too surprising given the simplicity of this function).

---

Note: for anybody who is actually testing some of this code, you might want to ensure you're back at the default level of 3:

```r
compiler::enableJIT(3)
```

Comment: This still leaves me with a mystery about vapply, but I guess that ought to be a separate question

Comment: Call `tri_nums` on the console and note that it ends with something like `<bytecode: 0x0000021e9d5ec1f8>`, _suggesting_ that it was byte-compiled.

Comment: `vapply` is about as fast as the `apply`-family of functions can be ... but ever since R-3, `for` loops can be faster given basic CS-principles. It's been a while, but every now and then I still see a question here on SO along the lines of *"my prof told me `for` loops are stupid slow, so I have to convert this simple process to a more-complicated `*apply` thingy"*.

Comment: It's interesting that, in my experimentation at least, `vapply` doesn't get the byte-compiling boost—wrapping the `vapply` in a function call makes it slower.

Comment: My guess is that byte-compiling does _so well_ here because the operations you're doing are completely mathematical and so-very-well optimizable. Start throwing in custom logic and/or other things, it it likely to narrow the margin between compiled and not.